# How to update a SQL database with an .xlsx file on server without Office installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-office, xlsx

How will you Import a .xlsx file to a sql database on a server that does not have Office installed on?

Since you can't use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of free native/XLSX file readers that are out there.  Try taking a look at this one:

http://koogra.sourceforge.net/

If your workbook is fairly straightforward, this is probably all you will need.

Answer (score 0):

If you've a little money to spend I cannot recommend this highly enough: http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/

Comment: ah.. I was hoping that it won't come to this. This the only way?

Comment: this and a lot of heartache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278328.aspx

Comment: Never used this, however if you're looking for open source, this might be worth checking out: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you stuck with native XLSX? Or are you open to Excel XML?

You know where I'm going with this...Excel XML is XML, and is "native" when opened in Excel (features intact).